# Writing MS Word 2007 with styles using Perl

Tags: perl, cpan

How can I write a .doc file using Perl with styles like background color, font color/name/size etc.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the CPAN module [Win32::Word::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/~johanl/Win32-Word-Writer-0.02/lib/Win32/Word/Writer.pm)